# how to make RegEx to match CSS non greedy for a part of the match

Tags: php, css, regex

I'm working on this RegEx to match and replace CSS with other CSS values.
So far I have this:

```
$css_new = preg_replace('/('.$definition.'.*?\s'.$property.':)[^;]*([^}]*)/is','$1 '.$value.'$2',$css_temp);
```

The issue I have is that if I am trying to replace something in the definition ".menu" values also get replaced in the ".menu li" definition.

I was thinking of adding a "{" somewhere but I'm not having luck with it.
I tried this:

```
$css_new = preg_replace('/('.$definition.'{.*?\s'.$property.':)[^;]*([^}]*)/is','$1 '.$value.'$2',$css_temp);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to report how I solved this problem.
I was able to come up with this line and have tested it extensively.

```
$css_new = preg_replace('/(.*^'.$definition.'\s{.*?\s'.$property.':)[^;]*([^}]*)/ism','$1 '.$value.'$2',$css_temp);
```

If you see something wrong with this line please let me know but I believe this solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `$definition` always contains the entire selector. (And note that you replace the dot in your definition before adding it to your regexp, else `.menu` would match `smenu` as well)

```
$definition = '.submenu';

// no match:
.menu .submenu
```

I also assume that the CSS is not entirely clean (so double spaces can occur etc.).

```
.menu    .submenu {
```

Next assumption is that multiple (comma) separated CSS rules do NOT exist (else you would be changing more than 1 rule):

```
.menu .submenu, .menu .list {
```

Then this should work: (not fully tested)

```
$cleanDefinition = str_replace(array('.', ' '), array('\.', '\s+'), $definition);
$result = preg_replace('/((?:}|^)\s*'.$cleanDefinition.'\s*{.*'.$property.'\s*:)(.+?)(;.*?})/is', '$1'.$value.'$3', $css_temp);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! All assumptions but the last one are correct. Can this code be changed to also change properties of multiple comm-.separated definitions?